# Error StackOverFlow

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento, recursión, quicksort

Tengo la clase operaciones la cual contiene los metodos de ordenamientos quicksort
y el método privado mediana, lo que deberia hacer el codigo es utilizar el metodo privado mediana para hallar el pivot y realizar el ordenamiento, no se como corregir el error no se que estoy haciendo mal, me gustaria su ayuda!Creo que el problema esta en la recursividad que se aplica en el metodo privado Quicksort
Estas son las lineas que me generan el error

int pivot = mediana(first, med, last);

y la otra linea

quicksort(low, j, first, med, last);

```
public class Ordenamiento {
    private int[] numbers;
    private int[] helper;
    private int number;
     int a, b,c;
 public void quickSort(int[] vector) {
        // Check for empty or null array
        if (vector == null || vector.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.numbers = vector;
        number = vector.length;
        a = vector[0];
        b = vector[(number - 1) / 2];
        c = vector[number - 1];
        quicksort(0, number - 1, a, b, c);
    }
    private void quicksort(int low, int high, int first, int med, int last) {
        int i = low, j = high;
        //Como ejercicio propuesto, queda que adapte el codigo para que use la mediana de tres
        int pivot = mediana(first, med, last);
        //numbers[low + (high - low) / 2];
        // Divide into two lists
        while (i <= j) {
            // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the left list
            while (numbers[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
            // element then get the next element from the right list
            while (numbers[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
            // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
            // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
            // values.
            // As we are done we can increase i and j
            if (i <= j) {
                exchange(i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // Recursion
        if (low < j) {
            quicksort(low, j, first, med, last);
        }
        if (i < high) {
            quicksort(i, high, first, med, last);
        }
    }

    private int mediana(int primer, int mitad, int ultimo) {
        int aux;
        int a = primer, b = mitad, c = ultimo;

        if (a > b) {
            if (a > c) {
                if (b > c) {

                    primer = c;
                    mitad = b;
                    ultimo = a;
                } else {
                    primer = a;
                    mitad = c;
                    ultimo = b;
                }
            } else {
                primer = b;
                mitad = a;
                ultimo = c;
            }
        } else {
            if (b > c) {
                if (a > c) {
                    primer = c;
                    mitad = a;
                    ultimo = b;

                } else {
                    primer = a;
                    mitad = c;
                    ultimo = b;

                }
            } else {
                primer = a;
                mitad = b;
                ultimo = c;
            }
        }
        return mitad;
    }

    private void exchange(int i, int j) {
        int temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[j];
        numbers[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: exacto.. fijate que si pasa el while, siempre pero siempre entra en el primer if... y asi eternamente...

Comment: Otra cosa.. esta pregunta, esta relacionada con tu pregunta anterior?

Comment: Si están relacionadas pero logre avanzar un poco mas en esta pregunta, me ayudas a solucionar el problema, lo haría yo misma pero recién estoy empezando con recursividad y todavía no lo capto del todo bien

Comment: hacele un seguimiento a tu codigo.. si low < j y i <= j entonces low es siempre menor que j... No tengo ni idea de toda tu logica ahi.. pero seguro que siempre entras por el primer if, y nunca vas por el segundo.. igual, no entiendo en que punto corta tu recursividad..  por favor, aclara si tu otra pregunta esta resuelta o no... las dos suenan, confusas...